# Delphi image canvas... paint an area (triangle, rectangle, polygons)

Tags: delphi

I have a variable number of points on a canvas.
Sometime its four other times 3 points, or 6.
Is there a function that can paint the area inside?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [`TCanvas.Polygon`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.Polygon) function. Declare an array of [`TPoint`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Types.TPoint), set its length to the count of your points, specify each point's coordinates (optionally modify canvas pen and/or brush) and pass this array to the [`TCanvas.Polygon`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.Polygon) function. Like in this boring example:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Points: array of TPoint;
begin
  SetLength(Points, 3);
  Points[0] := Point(5, 5);
  Points[1] := Point(55, 5);
  Points[2] := Point(30, 30);
  Canvas.Pen.Width := 2;
  Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clYellow;
  Canvas.Polygon(Points);
end;
```

Here's how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 16):

As a complement to TLama's excellent answer, this is a case where you can obtain pretty convenient syntax using the open array construct. Consider the helper function

```
procedure DrawPolygon(Canvas: TCanvas; const Points: array of integer);
var
  arr: array of TPoint;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(arr, Length(Points) div 2);
  for i := 0 to High(arr) do
    arr[i] := Point(Points[2*i], Points[2*i+1]);
  Canvas.Polygon(arr);
end;
```

defined and implemented once and for all. Now you can do simply

```
Canvas.Pen.Width := 2;
Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
Canvas.Brush.Color := clYellow;
DrawPolygon(Canvas, [5, 5, 55, 5, 30, 30]);
```

to draw the same figure as in TLama's example.

Comment: I'd be happy with this answer being the accepted one. Being first isn't the most important thing. Being best is!

Answer (score 15):

As a complement to both TLama's and Andreas answer, here's another alternative :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clYellow;
  Self.Canvas.Polygon( [Point(5,5), Point(55,5), Point(30,30)]);
end;
```

Utilizing open array construct and Point record.